# How can Diablo appear in Diablo III when his soulstone was destroyed in Diablo II?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-ii

I still don't understand this part. In Diablo II Diablo's soulstone is destroyed preventing his return forever but at the end of Diablo III we face him once again. How is this possible?

Comment: Did you just not read or listen to, like, any of the dialog over the course of the whole game?

Comment: @lesspop to be fair the story/plot in d3 is bad to the point where it reaches parody levels.

Comment: Well, sure. But there's a difference between a terrible plot you didn't even bother to read, and a terrible plot you've suffered through!

Comment: I actually didn't play Diablo 3. I only **read the plot on Wikipedia** and after I saw that they digged up Diablo again I dropped the idea of playing through it. Diablo 1/2 were my all time favorites and it seems that D3 is a disgrace to them. I have actually never said that I played with D3.

Comment: @AdamArold Well, if you haven't played, why are you asking?  This information is easily found in-game, and on the internet.  It kinda smacks of zero effort.

Comment: @Frank my only goal was to annoy you and it seems that I've succeeded.

Comment: I can see there is a vote war going on...so now I have ***1337*** rep please stop.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz In the last few years I have employed a form of *damage control* in my gaming life so I refrain from suffering through poop plots. I was just curious how they excavated Diablo (again).

Comment: It was still worth it! Keep downvoting! I need 24 more!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is all fairly well explained on various Wiki sites. The following is a quote from:

http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Diablo

I marked the relevant section in bold; in essence, the creation of the black soulstone drew all the souls of the evils into the stone, together with the one of Diablo. Leah then frees the souls, turning her into the physical incantation of the prime evil.

> Diablo spent two centuries slowly corrupting the Soulstone that
>   imprisoned him. In time, he was able to extend his influence into the
>   surrounding area and possess both King Leoric and his archbishop,
>   Lazarus. The King proved too strong to fully possess, so the Lord of
>   Terror took his son, Prince Albrecht. Diablo then began to shape an
>   outpost of Hell within the catacombs that ran beneath the town of
>   Tristram. By spreading terror into the surrounding countryside, the
>   Demon was able to attract many heroes who came to cleanse the land of
>   evil. By the time the strongest of these heroes, Aidan, reached this
>   goal, though, he had become fully influenced by the power of Diablo.
>   In his twisted state, Aidan believed that the only way to fully
>   control the Demon was to plunge Diablo's Soulstone into his own head.
>   This, of course, was exactly what Diablo had planned all along, as the
>   Demon now had an even stronger body to use to find his brothers and
>   complete his ultimate plan...
>
> Diablo eventually possessed Aidan and went to free his two brothers,
>   Mephisto and Baal. Diablo (as Aidan) met Adria the Witch, who knew
>   immediately that Aidan was possessed by Diablo, and swore eternal
>   servitude to Him. Eventually, a second party of adventurers confronted
>   Diablo and killed him. This time however, his Soulstone was destroyed
>   in the Hellforge, in an attempt to put an end to his evil permanently.
>
> **Unfortunately, the destruction of his Soulstone was not enough to end his evil. Upon the completion of the Black Soulstone by Zoltun
>   Kulle, the souls of all the slain Evils are drawn to the Stone
>   including Diablo (the location of souls after the slaying of the Evils
>   is still unknown). Adria betrayed humanity by helping Diablo possess
>   Leah, the vessel Adria bore 20 years before, the result of conception
>   of Adria and Diablo. Now that all evils are in one body, Diablo is
>   reincarnated as the Prime Evil and had begun his assault in the High
>   Heavens.** Unfortunately for him, Diablo was defeated by the Nephalem
>   and cast down from Heaven.
>
> While his brothers Baal and Mephisto prefer to play power-mongering
>   games from the shadows through scores of minions, Diablo seems content
>   to be the pure destructive power behind their machinations. This is
>   not to say that Diablo lacks the intelligence of his brothers (as he
>   rarely speaks), but being the youngest, he somewhat defers to their
>   direction and suggestions in the course of their scheming.

Comment: If they're combined, any idea why they call the "prime evil" Diablo, and not Mephisto or Baal?